# What is the purpose of "Secret Launch Files"?

Tags: windows-7, windows

I found this file in a subfolder under Documents.  What would be the purpose of this?

Comment: I think someone is using your computer for espionage.

Comment: How do you know it is their computer, sounds like Carole is snooping to me.

Answer (score 2):

This folder is not a system one so you should find first who created it to try to find its purpose.

Comment: Look at the parent folder / child folders as well.